# How to get different uname -n results

Tags: networking, redhat

I have two terminals each running two processes that are supposed to communicate with one another.  The way each process is able to communicate is by sending each other the results of `uname -n` and comparing it to values in a map to determine the type of the process.  Since I need the map to be unique I would like my terminals to return different results of `uname -n`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Run your commands on different hosts when you need uname to display different hostnames

Comment: does different host necessarily mean differed computers?

Comment: `uname -n` prints the name of the machine it's running on. So it is probably _not_ what you should be using in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Why not in terminal two create a shell function for uname ?

```
joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joe$ uname() 
> { 
>   echo "differentHostName" 
> }
joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joe$ uname - n 
differentHostName
```

Or you could create an alias

```
joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joe$ alias uname="echo differentHostname" 
joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joe$ uname
differentHostname
```

Cheers,
-Joe